# jQuery - get next element with same name as id of selected input

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

First off, I'd like to apologize for the horrid title there, but it was the best way I could think of summing up my issue.

Currently, I use a `jQuery` script that checks, on `blur` on an `input:text`, that the text value of the input is greater than a certain amount.  If not, the input is highlighted red - but what I'd like to happen next, is to have a `<p>` in an adjacent column to have it's text changed.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<tr>
      <td width="15%"><label for="example">Hello world</label></td>
      <td width="70%"><input type="text" class="" id="example" value=""/></td>
      <td width="15%"><p name="example"></p></td>
 </tr>
```

And my jQuery/css is :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .fail{
        border:2px red solid;
    }   
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* Inline, onBlur validation 
    Text */
    $('input:text').blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length <= 2) {
            $(this).attr('class', 'fail');
            }else{$(this).attr('class', '');}
    });
    </script>
```

Is it possible, on `blur` to somehow call the next element with the same `name` as the selected input's `id`, and then change it's text?  I know this must be a tough dynamic puzzle to solve, but it's something I really need.

In the past, I achieved the same effect by repeating the code for every element, but that's not really suitable here.

Thank you for any advice you can give me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

zzzzBov is correct however it would be better to use a context to improve efficiency and/or a tagname. In addition add a variable that references $(this).

```
var $this = $(this);
$('p[name="'+$this.attr('id')+'"]', $this.closest('tr')).text('foo bar baz');
```

---

**Edited after comment**
The difference between above and zzzzBov's answer is:

```
$('[name="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]')  
// will start traversing the DOM starting at the beginning of the 
// document. Largest search.

$('p[name="'+$this.attr('id')+'"]')
// will first call getElementsByTagName and try to find a match, smaller search.

$('p[name="'+$this.attr('id')+'"]', $this.closest('tr'))
// will only search the contents of the closest('tr') tag 
// that is an ancestor of your input. Even smaller search.
```

Generally speaking being more specific with jQuery selectors can improve preformance.  In addition using variable to store selected elements such as `var $this = $(this);` or `var $myElement = $('#myElement')` is more efficient than creating the same selectors over and over.  Remember jQuery is as efficient as it can be with the selectors but it is up to you to use them to thier potential.

Comment: `John Hartsock` how would that differ to @zzzzBov by using `parent`? I'm still new to `jQuery`, so forgive my ignorance there...

Comment: Ah, thank you John, I'll trial that now...I hadn't even thought of that kind of efficiency.  Thank you!  In light of your extra help there, I've given you my tick - thanks for your help!

Comment: `$(foo, bar)` is equivalent to `$(bar).find(foo)`

Comment: Also, while i completely agree with using the context, don't optimize prematurely

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the `blur` callback:

```
$('[name="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').text('foo bar baz');
```

Comment: That works perfectly for me, thank you so much!  Out of interest, this snippet should work to alter all other attributes, right?  As in, if is used `$('[name="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').attr('class', 'fail-text');`...?

Comment: you want to use the `addClass` function to add a class to a dom node.