# Modify this change function to use (this) and the next element with same name as the id of (this)

Tags: jquery, selector, this

This [Dropkick](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/) `change` function updates the value of another `<select>` element when an option is selected.  I'm using the function on 300+ pairs of `<select>` elements so I'd love to modify the function so as not to require specifying the selectors for each element.

Since the elements aren't positioned next to each other, I'd like to incorporate this method for getting the next element with same name as the id of the selected input [stackoverflow.com/a/7734190/1056713](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7734190/1056713)

**EDIT -** In order to simplify the example for this posting I've used a generic name and id for these elements, but the name of the 2nd element would match the id of the 1rst element.

A working example of the function is posted here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/yhAX5/6/

JS

```
$('#Select1').dropkick({
    change: function(value) {
        var $select2 = $('#Select2');
        removeDefaultFromSelect($select2);
        $select2.val(value);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<!-- Dropkick styled select element -->
<select name="DropkickSelect" id="Select1" class="dropkick">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select> 

<!-- Element who's value will be set  -->
<select name="Select1" id="Select2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: So if they are not adjacent, what is the relationship between the members of each pair of selects? How do you determine the one from the other?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot - I just added a sample of both <select> elements which hopefully clarifies that :-)

Comment: OK, I'll let TJC answer that. It's a light amendment to his current answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update below** *(question was updated)*

**Original answer**:

Oddly, `this` in the `change` callback isn't the select element, it's an array in which the `select` element seems to be the first entry. That's quite odd.

But using that information, you can get the `id` from `this[0]` and get the number from the `id` by removing all non-digits and parsing it, like this:

```
var idnum = parseInt(this[0].id.replace(/\D/g, ''), 10);
```

Then, of course, just add one to it to get the next select, so:

```
$('selector for the dropkick things to hook up').dropkick({
    change: function(value) {
        var idnum = parseInt(this[0].id.replace(/\D/g, ''), 10) + 1;
        var $nextSelect = $('#Select' + idnum);
        removeDefaultFromSelect($nextSelect);
        $nextSelect.val(value);
    }
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhAX5/7/)

Alternately, you could use a `data-*` attribute on each select to indicate what the other select it should use is, but if you're always numbering them in ascending order, that's probably more trouble than it's worth.

---

**Update**: Re your edit:

> ...but the name of the 2nd element would match the id of the 1rst element

That makes it even easier, you can just use an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('selector for the dropkick things to hook up').dropkick({
    change: function(value) {
        var $nextSelect = $('select[name="' + this[0].id + '"]');
        removeDefaultFromSelect($nextSelect);
        $nextSelect.val(value);
    }
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhAX5/8/)

Comment: TJ, see OP's clarification above.

Comment: The names and id #'s actually vary significantly amongst the elements, I was just using a generic name in an attempt to keep the question simple. I'm sorry that I wasn't more specific in the question :-( Can this approach be modified so that it just detects the text in the name and id selectors?

Comment: @ChayaCooper: That makes it even easier, I've updated the answer.

Comment: It's perfect :-D And it works using 'class' as the Dropkick selector (even though I realized that I hadn't been as clear as I should have been about wanting to use that :-))

Comment: Any chance that you'd know how to assign a 'click' function to this so that the function can be triggered when the element is clicked and not just when it's changed? Dropkick doesn't directly support click functions and I've had trouble getting the standard 'click' function to work here.

Comment: @ChayaCooper: Glad that helped. No, I'm afraid I don't know about the `click` thing, I've never used dropkick. Just assigning a `click` handler to the select doesn't immediately work (no great surprise, I assume dropkick is hiding it and replacing it with the fancy stuff). Good luck,

Comment: I figured it didn't hurt to ask, especially since it (at least theoretically) should be so much more straightforward than the problem that you solved so awesomely ;-D